# how to set image to right in Table view cell with basic style

Tags: ios, uitableview

is there any way to set image to right in Table view cell with basic style?

I have to implement arabic app with right sidemenu and need the image to be aligned to right in Table cell view

Comment: Are you using auto layout? how are you managing your language (Changing from iPhone settings or having the language setting in your app)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the semantic for the tableView itself and it should reverse the cells

**Swift:**

```
self.tableView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

**Objective-C:**

```
self.tableView.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft;
```

//

I have created a demo [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/lf8c239en4jfnma/hjesjhds.zip) check it , click the cell to reverse the whole table or the current semantic form En to Ar and vice versa

//

**Note:** You need to also set

```
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight; // Objective-C
```

Comment: it does not work cell.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft;

Comment: the parent is the content view ?